# Add and Read a List<t> using Gobal.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've researched Global.asax and Application_Start then searched the web for someone else's attempt to resolve this but found no such resource.

Question: 
Can we store a `List<t>` in Global Memory (Global.asax)? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like Application variables are your best bet. This is from memory, but I believe the syntax to access them is:

```
Application[ "MyVariable" ] = 123.45f;
```

You can access them from Global.asax or anywhere else.

For a List<>, the code would be something like:

```
Application[ "ValueList" ] = new List<float>();
( (List<float>)Application[ "ValueList" ] ).Add( 123.45f );
float myValue = ( (List<float>)Application[ "ValueList" ] )[ 0 ];
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip but that isn't a List<t>.

Comment: You can assign a list too - I'll update the answer to show that.

Comment: @QuadrupleA you'll need to cast when retrieving from Application state - eg `float myValue = ((List<float>)Application["ValueList"])[0];`

Answer (score 1):

You can not store itin Global.asax but you can store this in [asp.net cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsbfdd8c%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) or [application state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178594%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) The code for storing / retrieving could be in Global.asax or any other place within web application.

Comment: I had researched the [application state link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178594%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)  already and am able to save single values no problem but when it came to a collection/list, even a generic list such as List<t> I can't seem to be able to make it work or find documentation. Further you're incorrect when you say that we "can not store it in Global.asax" as the documentation on the link you gave shows that we can use `<object runat="server" scope="application" ID="MyInfo" 
    PROGID="MSWC.MYINFO">
</object>'. Thx but, using the asp.net cache doesn't answer the q.

Comment: IMO <object runat="server" scope="application" will save object in application not in Global.asax

Comment: My point was if I figured out (...had you helped show me how to) use the `<object runat="server" scope="application...` code... I would have marked you're reply as the answer. But you didn't... and that code does literally have to be typed into the Global.asax in order to be saved in Application State. No worries though, I really do appreciate you answering at all.